# Different ports for listening and reading

Tags: sockets, network-programming, p2p

Should I use different ports for listening and reading in a peer to peer application? If so, why not a single port for both listening and reading?

Comment: Are you talking about TCP or UDP ports? If TCP then you don't have to worry, as you use one socket (port) for listening for connections and when a new connection is accepted you get a new socket with a new port automatically.

Comment: Not exactly. TCP connection is identified by both ends IPs/ports. Thus, accepted connection can use the same IP/port on the server side as the listening socket. See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489036/how-does-the-socket-api-accept-function-work

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No you don't, you get a new TCP socket with the *same* local port number.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about TCP, you don't get the choice: accepted sockets use the same local port as the listening port (and outbound ports have to use a different port, if you need them). If you're talking about UDP, there's no reason to use more than one socket, so no occasion to use more than one port. So the answer in both cases is the same: use one port.