# How many tuples are there in a connection?

Tags: sockets, ip, protocols, port, tuples

[Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152457/what-is-the-difference-between-a-port-and-a-socket) said that there are 4 tuples in a connection

**client IP address, client port number, server IP address, server port number**

[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489036/how-does-the-socket-api-accept-function-work) said that there are 5

**client IP address, client port number, server IP address, server port number, protocol**

Which one is correct ?

Comment: Neither: there are 6 elements, missing the address family.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You've misunderstood the terminology. A TCP *connection* is identified by a 5-tuple. That means *one* tuple, with 5 elements. The five elements are:

1. Protocol. This is often omitted as it is understood that we are talking about TCP, which leaves 4.
2. Source IP address.
3. Source port.
4. Target IP address.
5. Target port.

Comment: doesn't that a socket identify a connection ?

Comment: @onmyway133 A TCP socket is an endpoint of a connection. It also has the 5-tuple associated with it, of course.

Comment: [RFC 9143](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9143.html#name-terminology) describes a _transport_ as a 5-tuple as well: `A collection of the following values: source address, source port, destination address, destination port, and transport-layer protocol.`

Comment: @JimB No it doesn't. It defines a 5-tuple as those words. No 'transport' about it.

Comment: @user207421 Not sure the distinction you're making here. The RFC says what it says.

Answer (score -1):

However, in a ICMP connection, it's identified by a 3-tuple :

1-Source IP address
2-Destination IP address
3-ICMP Identifier

Refer to : RFC 6146