# Filter network packet by process PID with libpcap

Tags: c, network-programming, pcap, netstat

Im trying to analyze traffic network using libpcap in C language. I would like to filter packets by process PID. I've been doing research and apparantly pcap can't do what I want but netstat can give me information about traffic with process pid.

Is this ugly to call "system("netstat - apn")" or is there any other library in C/C++ that I could use ? I want my programm running under Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `system(3)` is [generally frowned upon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/c-system-function-vulnerability) and you won't get the output of your command. If you want to go that route, use [`popen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125828/capturing-stdout-from-a-system-command-optimally).

Going an alternate route, on Linux-derived platforms, I would suggest combing `/proc` for details on the process you're interested in and use that to build a [`bpf` filter](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html). You should be able glean a  [four or five tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761436/how-many-tuples-are-there-in-a-connection) for your process from `/proc/$PID/net/{tcp, udp}` and use that to create a filter string to capture the packets you want.