# How can I have two websockets listening on the same HOST:PORT?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have made a simple web chat based on [gorilla sample chat](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat). 
The main room communicates with the server through:

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/room');
```

I have implemented user login and the room works fine. Now I'd like to let users to have also private chats. So I tried to define a new websocet to handle those communications:

```
pws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/private');
```

and I defined necessary routing and handling at the server side. However when I try to create a new websocket `pws` in the console, I get :

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/private' failed: Error
>   in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

And in the server I get:

> ServeHTTP:websocket: origin not allowed

So I'm wondering weather it is impossible to open a second socket on the same HOST:PORT? And if so, how to overcome this limitation?

I saw rather similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812865/can-i-open-2-ports-simultaneously-with-single-websocket-server) but without definitive answer, so appreciate your hints.

Comment: can you put functionality of both putative listeners into one listener

Comment: @ScottStensland, if by `putative listeners` you mean the server-side code, well, I just added a new `/private` route and duplicated the code that handles the `/room` socket (with a new room name). You can see those functions in the gorilla link in the question details.