# How could one single server socket communicate with multiple client sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I've seen this post

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html

since it wrote:

> If everything goes well, the server accepts the connection. Upon
>   acceptance, the server gets a new socket bound to the same local port
>   and also has its remote endpoint set to the address and port of the
>   client. It needs a new socket so that it can continue to listen to the
>   original socket for connection requests while tending to the needs of
>   the connected client.

So are there multiple server sockets which has the same port in the server side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489036/how-does-the-socket-api-accept-function-work

Comment: Yes, the server uses one predefined port number. Clients are probably using dynamic ports. The unique identifier for the socket is the clients IP and port number (in combination of the server socket of course).

Answer (score 4):

There is one [`ServerSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html). It accepts incoming connections through the [`accept`()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29) method. This returns a [`Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) which you use on the server side to handle the connection to a particular client.

Comment: also: that ServerSocket (internally) typically maintains a queue of listeners to handle the case where multiple connections arrive right after one another. The default is typically something like 50, so frequently you don't need to mess with it, but one of the  ServerSocket constructors (http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int,%20int)) will accept a parameter to let you increase that.

Comment: @JVMATL It doesn't maintain a 'queue of listeners'. It maintains, in the kernel, a backlog queue of already completed inbound connections.