# How many sockets do Google open for every request it receives?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, request, port

The following is my recent interview experience with a reputed network software company. I was asked questions about interconnecting TCP level and web requests and that confused me a lot. I really would like to know expert opinions on the answers. It is not just about the interview but also about a fundamental understanding of how networking work (or how application layer and transport layer cross-talk, if at all they do).

1. *Interviewer*: Tell me the process that happens behind the scenes when
   I open a browser and type `google.com` in it.

   *Me*: The first thing that happens is a socket is created which is 
   identified by `{SRC-IP, SRC-PORT, DEST-IP, DEST-PORT, PROTOCOL}`. The
   `SRC-PORT` number is a random number given by the browser. Usually the TCP/IP
   connection protocol (three-way handshake is established). Now
   both the client (my browser) and the server (Google) are ready to handle
   requests. (TCP connection is established).
2. *Interviewer*: Wait, when does the name resolution happen?

   *Me*: Yep, I am sorry. It should have happened before even the socket is created.
   DNS name resolve happens first to get the IP address of Google to
   reach at.
3. *Interviewer*: Is a socket created for DNS name resolution?

   *Me*: hmm, I actually do not know. But all I know DNS name resolution is 
   connectionless. That is, it's not TCP but UDP. Only a single
   request-response cycle happens. (So there is a new socket created for DNS
   name resolution).
4. *Interviewer*: `google.com` is open for other requests from other
   clients. So is establishing your connection with Google blocking
   other users?

   *Me*: I am not sure how Google handles this. But in a typical socket
   communication, it is blocking to a minimal extent.
5. *Interviewer*: How do you think this can be handled?

   *Me*: I guess the process forks a new thread and creates a socket to handle my
   request. From now on, my socket endpoint of communication with
   Google is this child socket.
6. *Interviewer*: If that is the case, is this child socket’s port number
   different than the parent one?

   *Me*: The parent socket is listening at 80 for new requests from
   clients. The child must be listening at a different port number.
7. *Interviewer*: How is your TCP connection maintained since your destination port number has changed. (That is the src-port number sent on Google's packet) ?

   *Me:*  The dest-port that I see as a client is always 80. When
   a response is sent back, it also comes from port 80. I guess the OS/the
   parent process sets the source port back to 80 before it sends back the
   post.
8. *Interviewer*: How long is your socket connection established with
   Google?

   *Me*: If I don’t make any requests for a period of time, the
   main thread closes its child socket and any subsequent requests from
   me will be like I am a new client.

   *Interviewer*: No, Google will not keep a dedicated child socket for
   you. It handles your request and discards/recycles the sockets right
   away.
9. *Interviewer*: Although Google may have many servers to serve
   requests, each server can have only one parent socket opened at port 80. The number of clients to access Google's webpage must be larger than the number of servers they have. How is this usually handled?

   *Me*: I am not sure how this is handled. I see the only way it could
   work is spawn a thread for each request it receives.
10. *Interviewer*: Do you think the way Google handles this is different from
    any bank website?

    *Me*: At the TCP-IP socket level, it should be
    similar. At the request level, slightly different because a session
    is maintained to keep state between requests for banks' websites.

If someone can give an explanation of each of the points, it will be very helpful for many beginners in networking.

Comment: Most likely the browser doesn't actually ask for a specific source port, and leaves it to the O/S to find a free port, since the browser isn't trying to serve any content. And DNS resolution is also handled by the O/S; which first checks the hosts file (on Lunix, that's /etc/hosts, and in Winblows that's some file under System32/drivers).

Comment: To contact the DNS server, a socket needs to be opened correct? and how server (google here) handles is more important I guess

Comment: Yep. A UDP packet needs to be sent.

Comment: @ParthianShot: Thanks, I kind of answered that correctly above I guess. I am wondering more on packet and request flow between servers (google here) and client

Comment: Possibly multiple, depending on whether resolution is being done recursively or iteratively, and whether the DNS server first accessed can find the record. You might need to check multiple DNS servers.

Comment: @ParthianShot: Thanks. That is clear on how DNS works - which operates at OS level

Comment: The easiest way to answer this question that I can think of would be to close all unnecessary networked apps, fire up wireshark, and watch the magic happen. Filtering based on your IP.

Comment: well, I can't see how many sockets google will open for the request they receive? and btw, I have wireshark is not working with my ISP

Comment: " Tell me the process that happens behind the scene when I open a browser and type google.com in it." Most of that process will be logged by wireshark, and "wireshark is not working with my ISP" ...Huh? Wireshark is a local program that passively monitors traffic going through your NIC. Not only does your ISP not know it's running, your ISP literally cannot know whether or not you're running a packet capture on traffic going through your machine. You could use wireshark, or fiddler, or just tcpdump or ethereal, or etherape...

Comment: None of your answers to the interviewer's question take into account that the client machine may have multiple NICs that need to be checked for a suitable route to Google, or that DNS may be performed locally first (host file) then through each NIC's gateway (so routers can perform DNS of LAN addresses) which would eventually hit the ISP gateway and work iteratively through ISP/Internet DNS servers, until a definite answer is finally reached. DNS itself supports both TCP and UDP (and yes, DNS involves a socket, but typically not one you create unless you are sending your own DNS queries)...

Comment: Once you have connected to Google, querying it does not block other users. Any worthwhile web server is not going to be single-threaded. Google is known to use [custom-made software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_platform) for its web servers and other online systems, so how it implements processing of concurrent requests is anyone's guess, but the sheer volume of traffic it has to handle is definitely NOT going to be synchronous/blocking.

Comment: It is very likely NOT spawning a new thread per request, that would never work in a scalable system as large as Google. You can't have a single server running tens of thousands of threads at a time, the OS would choke. Load balancing across multiple servers is very common in large systems, and each server has to manage its thread overhead, so handling multiple requests asynchronously in the same single thread is likely so fewer threads are needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I did not mean querying blocks the other users. It is the first time you get connected and (a socket and port allocated for your requests, this is could be blocking in theory, but very minimal)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Again see point 10: It is understood that Google is not serving on one server. Multiple servers are devoted and load balancing is achieved. But the proportion of servers to the request they receive is overwhelmingly high.

Comment: @brainstorm The initial connection is no more blocking than any other part of it, because of the existence of the TCP backlog queue.

Comment: Isn't the answer "I don't know!". Insofar as the browser developer uses standard system calls you may have a good idea how it does DNS resolution (ie. whether it involves opening a new socket), but without the source code you don't know for sure. Perhaps a better interview question should be "what is the current generally accepted best practice for what should happen when I open a browser and go to google.com?"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How many sockets do Google open for every request it receives?

This question doesn't actually appear in the interview, but it's in your title so I'll answer it. Google doesn't open any sockets at all. Your browser does that. Google *accepts connections,* in the form of new sockets, but I wouldn't describe that as 'opening' them.

> Interviewer : Tell me the process that happens behind the scene when I open a browser and type google.com in it.
>
> Me : The first thing that happens is a socket is created which is identified by {SRC-IP, SRC-PORT, DEST-IP, DEST-PORT, PROTOCOL}.

No. The *connection* is identified by the tuple. The socket is an endpoint to the connection.

> The SRC-PORT number is a random number given by browser.

No. By the operating system.

> Usually TCP/IP connection protocol (three way handshake is established). Now the both client (my browser) and server (google) are ready to handle requests. (TCP connection is established)
>
> Interviewer: wait, when does the name resolution happens?
>
> Me: yep, I am sorry. It should have happened before even the socket is created. DNS name resolve happens first to get the IP address of google to reach at.
>
> Interviewer : Is a socket created for DNS name resolution?
>
> Me : hmm, Iactually do not know. But all I know DNS name resolution is a connection-less. That is it not TCP but UDP. only a single request-response cycle happens. (so is a new socket created for DNS name resolution).

Any rationally implemented browser would delegate the entire thing to the operating system's Sockets library, whose internal functioning depends on the OS. It might look at an in-memory cache, a file, a database, an LDAP server, several things, before going out to a DNS server, which it can do via either TCP or UDP. It's not a great question.

> Interviewer: google.com is open for other requests from other clients. so is establishing you connection with google is blocking other users?
>
> Me: I am not sure how google handles this. But in a typical socket communication, it is blocking to a minimal extent.

Wrong again. It has very little to do with Google specifically. A TCP server has a separate socket per accepted connection, and any rationally constructed TCP server handles them completely independently, either via multithreading, muliplexed/non-blocking I/O, or asynchronous I/O. They don't block each other.

> Interviewer : How do you think this can be handled?
>
> Me : I guess the process forks a new thread and creates a socket to handle my request. From now on, my socket endpoint of communication with google is this this child socket.

Threads are created, not 'forked'. Forking a process creates another process, not another thread. The socket isn't 'created' so much as accepted, and this would normally precede thread creation. It isn't a 'child' socket.

> Interviewer: If that is the case, is this child socket’s port number different than the parent one.?
>
> Me: The parent socket is listening at 80 for new requests from clients. The child must be listening at a different port number.

Wrong again. The accepted socket uses the same port number as the listening socket, and the accepted socket isn't 'listening' at all, it is *receiving* and *sending.*

> Interviewer: how is your TCP connection maintained since your Dest-port number has changed. (That is the src-port number sent on google's packet) ?
>
> Me: The dest-port as what I see as client is always 80. when request is sent back, it also comes from port 80. I guess the OS/the parent process sets the src port back to 80 before it sends back the post.

This question was designed to explore your previous wrong answer. Your continuation of your wrong answer is still wrong.

> Interviewer : how long is your socket connection established with google?
>
> Me : If I don’t make any requests for a period of time, the main thread closes its child socket and any subsequent requests from me will be like am a new client.

Wrong again. You don't know anything about threads at Google, let alone which thread closes the socket. Either end can close the connection at any time. Most probably the server end will beat you to it, but it isn't set in stone, and neither is which if any thread will do it.

> Interviewer : No, google will not keep a dedicated child socket for you. It handles your request and discards/recycles the sockets right away.

Here the ***interviewer*** is wrong. He doesn't seem to have heard of HTTP keep-alive, or the fact that it is the default in HTTP 1.1.

> Interviewer: Although google may have many servers to serve requests, each server can have only one parent socket opened at port 80. The number of clients to access google webpage must be exceeding larger than the number of servers they have. How is this usually handled?
>
> Me : I am not sure how this is handled. I see the only way it could work is spawn a thread for each request it receives.

Here you haven't answered the question at all. He is fishing for an answer about load-balancers or round-robin DNS or something in front of all those servers. However his sentence "the number of clients to access google webpage must be exceeding larger than the number of servers they have" has already been answered by the existence of what you are both incorrectly calling 'child sockets'. Again, not a great question, unless you've reported it inaccurately.

> Interviewer : Do you think the way Google handles is different from any bank website?
>
> Me: At the TCP-IP socket level, it should be similar. At the request level, slightly different because a session is maintained to keep state between requests in Banks websites.

You almost got this one right. HTTP sessions to Google exist, as well as to bank websites. It isn't much of a question. He should be asking for facts, not your opinion.

Overall, (a) you failed the interview completely, and (b) you indulged in *far* too much guesswork. You should have simply stated 'I don't know' and let the interview proceed to things that you do know about.

Comment: ok. clarification needed 1) you mention "A TCP server has a separate socket per accepted connection" which is absolutely correct. But that is only for accepted connection. Server socket is open for listening. First time a request from client is made, it needs to create a new Socket and delegate the work to that socket. Only the TCP connection is established. Till new socket creation is not finished, the main Thread will be blocked (but that would be very very minimal still blocked yet). Does this make sense?

Comment: And one important point: for a typical client who is browsing using PC and opening three tabs in browser with different urls, three sockets are created by OS with IP:port pair. For a connection, it becomes four pair SRC-IP, SRC-PORT and DEST-IP, DEST-SRC correct?

Comment: @brainstorm The TCP server opens 1 listening socket; it loops calling `accept()` to receive sockets, and either starts a thread to handle them, enters them into a `select()` FD set, or starts some asynchronous stuff. `accept()` is blocking, and the accept loop is a rate-determining step, but it's saying too much to assert that it blocks other clients. Other clients can continue to *connect*, because of the backlog queue. They won't get *service* until the accept loop gets around to accepting them, but that should be quick enough to be imperceptible, unless the server is poorly programmed.

Comment: @brainstorm You can't equate browser tabs with sockets. The browser uses a connection pool so there is no 1:1. And loading a page may require loading images, .css/.js files, etc, which is usually done in parallel by multiple sockets.

Answer (score -1):

For point #6, here is how I understand it: if both ends of an end to end connection were the same as that of another socket, there would indeed be no way to distinguish both socket, but if a single end is not the same as that of the other socket, then it's easy to distinguish both. So there is not need to turn destination port 80 (the default) forth and back, since the source ports differ.