# OPNET Simulation - Unable to establish multiple TCP connection on the same port

Tags: tcp, opnet

From my understanding, A TCP session is identified as  `<ServerIP, ServerPort, ClientIP, ClientPort>`.

For instance, the session `<192.168.0.1, 80, 192.168.0.2, 1000>` is separated from `<192.168.0.1, 80, 192.168.0.2, 1001>`, and these two sessions can co-exist on the hosts simultaneously.

However, in OPNET, if `<192.168.0.1, 80, 192.168.0.2, 1000>` is already established, then `<192.168.0.1, 80, 192.168.0.2, 1001>` cannot be established because port 80 of 192.168.0.1 is already in use.

Given this model, if I try to host a HTTP service on 192.168.0.1:80, there can only be 1 connection to my server at a time, which severely limits the simulation capability.

Please confirm whether the model is indeed problematic, or is there anything I have overlooked. Also a workaround solution would be very appreciated.

Comment: It looks like some bug in OPNET. Just check out this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489036/how-does-the-socket-api-accept-function-work

Comment: I too think it is a bug, but what weird is that OPNET is a world class communication network simulation software, I cannot imaging that it would  has such a low level bug.

Comment: What error do you get when trying another connection to server at port 80?

Comment: The error is "TCP OPEN failed - Port is already in use."

Answer (score 1):

I dug into the source code of OPNET TCP model, and found the bug.

First of all, OPNET does consider `<192.168.0.1, 80, 192.168.0.2, 1000>` and `<192.168.0.1, 80, 192.168.0.2, 1001>` as two separate and independent sessions, and it can distinguish them using a `session_key`.

However, there is a minor bug in the model. When an open request is issued to the TCP model layer (either `PASSIVE`(listen) or `ACTIVE`(connect)), the model will check if the local port is being used. If the local port is being used, a error signal will be returned regardless of the type of open request, whereas the correct action is to only check for `ACTIVE` open.

A solution is to modify the check procedure to only work for `ACTIVE` open case. Preliminary test shows that multiple connection can be established on the same listening port now.