# Suppose I have a local server on my machine that capitalizes strings it receives, then returns them. How does it interact with ports?

Tags: server, tcp, network-programming

Speaking in high-level terms, suppose I have a server that capitalizes whatever strings it receives on the port it is listening to, and then returns them. It is on the same physical machine as the applications sending/reading the strings. For definiteness, we're on Linux or Windows. Would the following correctly describe the situation?

Our server interacts with two connections. The first is a connection from the application sending the string from `localhost:port1`, and the server is listening on `localhost:port2`. Then, after processing, it sends the capitalized string from `localhost:port3` to an application listening on `localhost:port4` that can read the packet.

So we have: `localhost:port1 -(lowercase string)-> localhost:port2`; then `localhost:port3 -(uppercase string)-> localhost:port4`.

Would this be an accurate portrait of how our server would interact with the machine's ports? In particular, must `port1` through `port4` be actually distinct ports?

Comment: It depends how they are connected. If both applications are clients, the server only uses one port. If the server is a client of the second application, there are four ports.

Comment: @user207421 I see! But in what sense would the server use only one port? Suppose both applications are clients of our server. Then, does the server interact with one port for listening and one port for returning the capitalized string?

Comment: No. The server listens on a local port and accepts connections. The accepted connections use the same local port.

Comment: Duplicate of [How does the socket API accept() function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489036/how-does-the-socket-api-accept-function-work) and many others.

Comment: @user207421 For the moment that link clarifies it, thank you very much for your help and time!